# How can I tell a program to use a different language under Windows?

Tags: windows, flash, language

There's a program which hasn't got any option to change the language. It automatically detects it. Now, I want it to display the original language, because the translation is not satisfactory. How do I do it?

If it helps, it seems that the program is just a SWF file converted to .exe

Answer (score 1):

If your program chooses language based on system settings, the [Application Compatibility Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562082(v=vs.85).aspx) might have a shim that allows those to be overridden.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I've never heard of ACT and it seems like a very useful program. Meanwhile I found out that the program I refer to in OP seems to use `Capabilities.language` in ActionScript, which I suspect to use one of the [Multilingual User Interface Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which are all in the Kernel32 library. Unfortunately, according to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd837644%28v=ws.10%29.aspx "you cannot use a shim to fix kernel-mode code". Thank you for your suggestion anyway.

Comment: @user2009388: The kernel32 library is _not_ kernel-mode. Like all other libraries it runs in userspace; it just happens to be called "kernel32", since most of its functions are wrappers around actual kernel syscalls. AppCompat can easily patch these wrappers though, or if necessary even the program itself.

Comment: I'm not able to find a proper fix. ACT also seems to lack proper documentation. After researching a bit I've only had luck with API Monitor, but it seems like an overkill. Maybe I'll try to program a hook myself.

Answer (score 0):

> It automatically detects it. Now, I want it to display the original
>   language, because the translation is not satisfactory. How do I do it?

You don't.  If the program does not have to option to switch languages then you are out of luck.  You would need the source code to the program itself to change this behavior.

Comment: People are going to have to explain the problem with this answer.  Is there something technically incorrect about my statement?  If you are going to issue a downvote I would appreciate a specific and logical reason to be shared before doing so.